# Drupal 6 Image Resize Thumbnail Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: media

We have a content type which has an original image.  There is also a resized version which is not a thumbnail, but not the original size either which is used on a drill down page.

What is the best way to maintain the image aspect ratio for this drilled down page image?  I've found some functions, but is there a module or best practice way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the ImageCache module https://drupal.org/project/imagecache there are also additional actions if you require them https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions

Comment: We have imagecache installed.  I check image cache_actions and I don't think that has what I need.

Comment: You might not think it does what you want but I know it does. Hence answering the question. http://i.imgur.com/wTp5gFn.jpg Once you've accepted it can do it, what you'll need to do is use the imagecache functions within your code, module or view and you're singing.